# Есть альтернатива list.index(i)?

Tags: python, list

list.index(i) возвращает положение первого элемента со значением i. 
Мне же нужно, чтобы возвращалось положение каждого элемента со значением i.
Есть ли альтернатива?
Бонусный вопрос: а почему именно первый элемент? Откуда такое ограничение?

Comment: Она возвращает элемент списка с указаным индексом. Или может я что-то путаю? В таком случае, какое значение вы запихнете в "i"  - это уже зависит только от Вас.  А "Бонусные" вопросы стоит задаваить в отдельных бонусных вопросах. И  назначать за них награду.

Comment: @V.March не, оно возвращает позицию элемента со значением `i`

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Спасибо за уточнение. Этого не знал еще. А штука таки удобная.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,1,5,6,1,8,9,1,1,0]
searchfor = 1

indices = [x[0] for x in list(enumerate(my_list)) if x[1]==searchfor]
print(indices)
```

Результат:

```
[0, 4, 7, 10, 11]
```

Первый индекс возвращается потому, что так было задумано - это быстрый метод, он должен вернуть наименьший индекс, по возможности, избежав прохода по всему итерируемому объекту.

Comment: Можно слегка упростить — необязательно оборачивать `enumerate` в `list`.